# custom config not loading in codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter

A couple of years ago we upgraded our CI2 sited to the then dev branch of CI3.

We are now updating these sites to the most recent CI 3.0.1

For some reason, custom config files are no longer being loaded.

Example syntax we use is:

```
$autoload['config'] = array('my_config','my_config_admin');
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what we might be missing?

Comment: Have you placed the config files in config folder would be use full to show one of them also

Comment: Yes they are there.  We imported the old ones into application/config

eg custom config therein is:

`code`$config['this_site_portal_id']=1;`code`